# a function that takes 3,1,2 and returns 1,2,3 respectively and vice verse

Tags: function, numbers

Is there a function that takes 1,2,3 and returns 3,1,2 respectively and vice-verse.
 eg:   f(1)=3
    f(2)=1
    f(3)=2

This is required to get the cyclic order eg 1 when gone left will be 3 , 2 will be 1 and 3 will be 2. 
1 when gone right will be 2 , 2 will be 3 and 3 will be 1.

Comment: Are you trying to randomly shuffle the values, or does it have to always be in this exact order?

Comment: Yes, there is such a function. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Agree with Jesse. Although it looks like, in fact, there are a whole *range* of such functions :-)

Comment: Was the question asking if there is a *unique* function, or at least one? :)

Comment: its for c# but any language would work! mrjoltcola gave a good answer but still looking for a reverse one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python:

```
def f(x):
    return ((x+4)%3)+1
```

In C:

```
int f(int x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
    case 1: return 3;
    case 2: return 1;
    case 3: return 2;
    default: return x;
    }
    return x;
 }
```

Although the mod (%) solution would work in C as well.

Answer (score 5):

If the inputs and outputs are always the same ie 1,2,3 should return 3,1,2 then the most effiecent thing to do is to have something like this. Why bother with math functions with such limited ins and outs...

```
function(x)
{
    if (x == 1) return 3;
    if (x == 2) return 1;
    if (x == 3) return 2;
    !throw some unsupported error!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

f(x) = floor(3/x) + floor(x/3)

Answer (score 3):

f(x) = (x + 1) mod 3 + 1

Comment: Wouldn't that return values in the range 0-2 in most programming languages?

Comment: thanks mrjoltcola also the reverse is required to go clockwise ie 3,1,2==> 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

Just make your own function to do it:

```
function(x) {
  var lookup = [3, 1, 2];
  return lookup[x - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None but you can create your own function.